# Why is simple PHP header authorization not working

Tags: php

I have the following code which I use on three sites that are all hosted through the same account:

```
$username = 'test'; 
$password = 'test';

If (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])|| !isset($_SERVER ['PHP_AUTH_PW'])||
    ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)){

//send this if the user and pass arent correct

header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm= "mysite"');
exit('<h2> Go away Creep!!</h2> you need a username and password to enter this kingdom!!');
}
```

It worked completely fine until I upgraded to a newer box a few days ago. Hosting company says everything is good on their end and server migration went fine, yet this script all of the sudden does not work. I input proper user and pass and the dialog simply prompts me again for the user and pass.

What could have possibly changed that would make this code not work? Is there something in htaccess that could someone be influencing it? Server settings?

PHP version on new box is 5.2 but I can upgrade to 5.3

Any help appreciated.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) so you can see what you're actually being passed.

Comment: Depends on the SAPI. In CGI and FastCGI environments the PHP_AUTH_USER thing won't be present, and the Authorization: header suppressed for security reasons. Look into the manual comments for workarounds then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the values from a phpinfo() call? If `safe_mode` is set to `on` I don't think you're able to access the `PHP_AUTH_*` server variables. The good news is that safe mode is gone in PHP 5.4, so if you can upgrade that may take care of things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...just checked, but safe mode is set to off.

Comment: Are you seeing the expected values in the PHP_AUTH_* variables?

Comment: having trouble dumping or echoing them before header prompts for input again. what is the best way to this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm. Make sure your .htpass file is still in the right spot/has the right permissions/is working properly. If that's working, add a querystring parameter that can override the authorization check.